# Passing parameters from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I append a URL with an email address that a user inputs, and then submits this email address via button? I am using a modal that will pop up, ask for the email, and then call the url when the user hits the submit button. (jQuery is supported) Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

```
<div id="emailModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel"> We Can Help</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

              <h6> Enter your information in the fields below to reset a forgotten password, or to restore access to an account that has been locked for security </h6>
              <br>
               <form >

                    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address">
                   <!-- <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                       <a href="#"><input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                    </label></a> -->

                  </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">

                <button class="m-btn blue" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can easily update the `action` property of the form when the button's clicked, and submit the data that way.  No need for ajax for this.

Comment: So you would have <form action="somepage.html" method="get"> and then how would you append the email to the url?

Comment: I've added an answer, and there's an alternative answer by @agrothe if you do want to use ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the form to this...

```
<form action="some-url.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address">
</form>
```

and add this script...

```
$("#emailModal button").on("click", function() {
    $("#emailModal form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
$("#emailModal .m-btn").click(function(){
   $.post("/my/url?email=" + $("#emailModal input.input-block-level").val(), function(){
      // this function is called on POST finish.
   });
   return false;
});
```

I think this is what you are after.